# Rearrange Array According to parent

Tags: php

I have an example array that contains this data.

[image]

How to rearrange this array in such a way that all the children will automatically follow its parent just like this.

[image]

Comment: Add a new column `tmp_sort`: if `PARENT ID` is 0, set value to ID, otherwise set value to `PARENT ID`. Then, do a normal hierarchical sort; first by `tmp_sort`, then by `PARENT ID`

Comment: the 2nd table, ID 162 & 163 should be *Parent B* instead of *Parent 2*, isn't it? also, are you using a database, or just an array in PHP?

Comment: @Raptor im just using an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I drafted a solution (might not be optimal, but it works for your case):

```
<?php
$people = array(
    [ 'id' => 153, 'caption' => 'Parent A', 'parent_id' => 0],
    [ 'id' => 155, 'caption' => 'Parent B', 'parent_id' => 0],
    [ 'id' => 159, 'caption' => 'Parent A Child 1', 'parent_id' => 153],
    [ 'id' => 160, 'caption' => 'Parent A Child 2', 'parent_id' => 153],
    [ 'id' => 161, 'caption' => 'Parent A Child 3', 'parent_id' => 153],
    [ 'id' => 162, 'caption' => 'Parent B Child 1', 'parent_id' => 155],
    [ 'id' => 163, 'caption' => 'Parent B Child 2', 'parent_id' => 155],
    [ 'id' => 166, 'caption' => 'Parent A Child 1 Grandchild 1', 'parent_id' => 159],
    [ 'id' => 167, 'caption' => 'Parent A Child 1 Grandchild 2', 'parent_id' => 159],
);



function cmp($a, $b) {
    return strcmp($a['parent_id'], $b['parent_id']);
}

// Step 1: Sort people by "PARENT ID" (optional, as it's already sorted)
usort($people, "cmp");

// Step 2: Find all childs by parent ID
$temp = array();
foreach($people as $key => $person) {
    if($person['parent_id'] == 0) {
        $temp[] = $person; // add the "Parent A" first
        unset($people[$key]); // remove the added parent
        $children = getPersonByParentId($people, $person['id']);
        foreach($children as $key2 => $child) {
            $temp[] = $child;
            unset($people[$key2]);
            $grandchildren = getPersonByParentId($people, $child['id']);
            foreach($grandchildren as $key3 => $grandchild) {
                $temp[] = $grandchild;
                unset($people[$key3]);
            }
        }
    }
}

function getPersonByParentId(&$people, $id) {
    $result = array();
    foreach($people as $key => $person) {
        if($person['parent_id'] == $id) {
            $result[] = $person;
            unset($people[$key]); // remove the selected one
        }
    }
    return $result;
}

print_r($temp);

?>
```

which will print:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 153
            [caption] => Parent A
            [parent_id] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 159
            [caption] => Parent A Child 1
            [parent_id] => 153
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 166
            [caption] => Parent A Child 1 Grandchild 1
            [parent_id] => 159
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 167
            [caption] => Parent A Child 1 Grandchild 2
            [parent_id] => 159
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 160
            [caption] => Parent A Child 2
            [parent_id] => 153
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 161
            [caption] => Parent A Child 3
            [parent_id] => 153
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [id] => 155
            [caption] => Parent B
            [parent_id] => 0
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [id] => 162
            [caption] => Parent B Child 1
            [parent_id] => 155
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [id] => 163
            [caption] => Parent B Child 2
            [parent_id] => 155
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another quick solution is to build a parent-child mapping, so we can do hierarchy generation faster and easily.

```php
$people = array(
    [ 'id' => 153, 'caption' => 'Parent A', 'parent_id' => 0],
    [ 'id' => 155, 'caption' => 'Parent B', 'parent_id' => 0],
    [ 'id' => 159, 'caption' => 'Parent A Child 1', 'parent_id' => 153],
    [ 'id' => 160, 'caption' => 'Parent A Child 2', 'parent_id' => 153],
    [ 'id' => 161, 'caption' => 'Parent A Child 3', 'parent_id' => 153],
    [ 'id' => 162, 'caption' => 'Parent B Child 1', 'parent_id' => 155],
    [ 'id' => 163, 'caption' => 'Parent B Child 2', 'parent_id' => 155],
    [ 'id' => 166, 'caption' => 'Parent A Child 1 Grandchild 1', 'parent_id' => 159],
    [ 'id' => 167, 'caption' => 'Parent A Child 1 Grandchild 2', 'parent_id' => 159],
);

$formatted = [];
$childs = [];
foreach($people as $data){
    // array to hold each person data as value and its id as key, so we can fetch data just using key from array.
    $formatted[$data['id']] = $data;
    // An associative array where parent_id as key and childs as an array at that key.
    $childs[$data['parent_id']][] = $data['id'];
}
// Considering all first level person has parent_id as 0. Begin our parent child traversal from root node(0).
$final = getChilds(0);

// Use depth first search to get childs using recursion.
function getChilds($parentId){
    global $childs, $formatted;
    
    if(isset($childs[$parentId])){
        $parentChild = [];
        foreach($childs[$parentId] as $child){
            $parentChild[] = $formatted[$child];
            $parentChild =  array_merge($parentChild, getChilds($child));
        }
        
        return $parentChild;
    }
    else{
        return [];
    }
}

echo '<pre>'; print_r($final);die;
```

Output:

```
<pre>Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 153
            [caption] => Parent A
            [parent_id] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 159
            [caption] => Parent A Child 1
            [parent_id] => 153
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 166
            [caption] => Parent A Child 1 Grandchild 1
            [parent_id] => 159
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 167
            [caption] => Parent A Child 1 Grandchild 2
            [parent_id] => 159
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 160
            [caption] => Parent A Child 2
            [parent_id] => 153
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 161
            [caption] => Parent A Child 3
            [parent_id] => 153
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [id] => 155
            [caption] => Parent B
            [parent_id] => 0
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [id] => 162
            [caption] => Parent B Child 1
            [parent_id] => 155
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [id] => 163
            [caption] => Parent B Child 2
            [parent_id] => 155
        )

)
```